# Export form data not working

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am working on `Sitecore 9.0.2` with `Sitecore 9 Forms`. When I am trying to export the form data, it shows me that "**The list is being exported**" but I get nothing.

Below is the screenshot for reference:-

[image]

This message I see when I select `Complete List` in the export wizard.

[image]

I get a different message when I select a specific `Date Range` like below:-

[image]

[image]

When I looked into the console I found `401 Status` for export data request.

[image]

Is there any configuration to export form data which I am missing?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have data (for that form) in the database? Query your database to be sure - I've seen this message when there was no data.

Comment: @Gatogordo I checked the data in myproject_ExperienceForms and there is no data in [FormEntry] and [FieldData] table. But simultaneously I checked the myproject_Reporting database and found data in Fact_FormFieldMetrics and Fact_FormMetrics tables. Both these table consist form id similar to the forms in sitecore.
What does that mean?

Comment: @Gatogordo As per you answer, I have added the "Save data" submit action and placed it before the redirection to Thankyou page and now I am getting data saved in database. Also I am able to download the data for a single form one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this behavior when there is no data for the form in the database. 
As mentioned in the comments, that seems to be your case.

Check if your form has the "`Save data`" submit action. This will save the data in the database.

Also make sure that this submit action is not preceded with a redirect action as that would abort the execution of subsequent steps (all actions after a redirect are not performed).

If needed, check in the web database that the save data action is present - it might be not published.

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/working-with-submit-actions.html

Comment: Is there any other interface where we can see the form data for all the forms at one place?

Comment: Don't think so.. not ootb.

Comment: I am having " save data" option still unable to export data. Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure you have data? If so, call Sitecore Support.