# Can't Export Sitecore Form Saved Results to CSV File

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm having a strange issue with Sitecore forms. I am trying to use Sitecore forms to save data entered in a form, and then export all entered data to a CSV file.

It was my understanding that this should all work OOTB with Sitecore Forms. When I go to the Form Designer Page and click "Export to a CSV File" on my test form, it shows the following notification:
[image]

However, the second notification that supposedly indicates that the CSV export is complete never shows. As such, I have no idea where I should navigate to access the CSV file.

Any idea/suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you have actual data? Check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19601/export-form-data-not-working The message is not very clear, but this happens when there is no data.