# Export Form Reports to CSV

Tags: sitecore-forms

How can you `Export to CSV` in the Form Reports Sitecore 9.1 from the Content Tree, as you can with Sitecore 8.2 WFFM?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see any option to export form data from content tree in Sitecore 9 however you can export form data from Sitecore Forms interface by selecting a form as shown below:-

[image]

Also you can have a look into [Export form data not working](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19601/export-form-data-not-working) for more detail.

Let me know if this helps you.