# Unable to Export Sitecore Form Data, throwing 401 unauthorized

Tags: sitecore-forms

[image: Export Complete Form Data]

Export Form Data requests are failed with below message.

```
https://abc.com/renew/api/ExportFormData/ExportToExcel?formId=%7BDDEB5360-F0BA-4BD2-B73C-424A61B9B20B%7D&isDateRange=false&token=1787417648793
```

> {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

I have verified the form db to check the submissions and they are adding to db properly.
Trying to export the data with an `Admin` user.
Version: `Sitecore 10.2`

Comment: Did you check this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19601/export-form-data-not-working

Comment: @GauravAgarwal - I can see the data in the DB still it's not working

Comment: Does it work in private tab in your browser?

Comment: @MarekMusielak - It does not work in the private tab also, I realized we are not using the OOTB '/sitecore/api/ssc/forms/exportdata' instead using our own controller to download the data into Excel.
This custom controller is marked with [authorize] filter and the error is coming from there.
One confusing thing is, this issue comes when users have multiple sessions running, and if the user changes the password and tries to download from the same window it works.

In the non-working scenario, if I debug and check, the context user is not resolved and is identified as anonymous

Answer (score 0):

I created a more advanced Sitecore Form Submission Report that will provide your report data in a datatables grid, which allows you to sort and search, and allows the report data to be copied to the clipboard, saved as a CSV, or saved as a PDF. The following page describes how I created it and contains the full code:

[Sitecore Form Submission Report](https://markfairblog.com/blog/sitecore-form-submission-report/)